# Bibliography not appearing and undefined citations

Tags: biblatex

I am writing my thesis and  really struggle with setting up bibliography. I read tons of similar issues here, but nothing seems to work for me. 
I created bib file wth texlive and I am working with texmkaker. In preamble I have

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,autocite=inline]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
```

and

```
\printbibliography
```

under the chapters.

and an example of my bib reference

```
@article{tugrul2004effect,
  title={The effect of weathering on pore geometry and compressive strength of selected rock types from Turkey},
  author={Tuǧrul, Atiye},
  journal={Engineering Geology},
  volume={75},
  number={3-4},
  pages={215--227},
  year={2004},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
```

all the citations are undefined.

Does anyone know what I can do to get my citations right in the text and my reference list to actually appear in the text?

Comment: You need to run Biber on your document for the citations and bibliography to appear. A complete compilation cycle will involve running LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX (where "LaTeX" is your favourite flavour of LaTeX: it can be pdfLaTEX, LuaLaTeX, XeLaTeX). Why Biber needs to be run is explained brilliantly in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 contains instructions to set up your editor to run Biber for you.

Comment: I tried to run pdflatex, bibtex, pdflatex and all the other combinations that were mentioned. nothing helped

Comment: You need to run **Biber** and not BibTeX. You may have to configure your editor for Biber before you can do that, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864.

Comment: **bibtex** is not **biber**

Comment: Crosspost https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=112588#p112577

Comment: I would love to know where you lost track to make the page better digestible for everyone else.

Comment: I don't have configure texmaker option so I am not sure how to run biber.

Comment: have tried the other ways to run biber in the link but I end up with still no references

Comment: Do you use TeXmaker? What can you see under "Options"? Is the "Configure Texmaker" option maybe present in one of the other menu items (maybe File or Edit)?

Comment: I have a mac so it was harder to find. But I did and I ran Pdflatex, Bibtex(Biber), pdflatex, pdflatex. Still nothing have changed

Comment: Ah yes, for some reason the config menu item is often somewhere else on a Mac (not sure why, probably "historical reasons"). If you did indeed run Biber you should be able to find a `.blg` file (it's a normal text file): Open it and upload its complete contents to the question.

Comment: I get an error though when I run biber 
INFO - This is Biber 2.11 INFO - Logfile is 'Maintex.aux.blg'

ERROR - Cannot find control file 'Maintex.aux.bcf'! - Did latex run successfully on your .tex file before you ran biber? INFO - ERRORS: 1

Comment: You seem to have slightly misconfigured your editor. You need to make sure it runs Biber on the basename of your file; not on the `.aux`: You probably have set your Biber call to something like `biber %.aux`, but you need `biber %` **without the `.aux`**.

Comment: oh my god FINALLY it s there.  I have been struggling with it for 3 days now, THANK YOU for patience and help!

Comment: Glad to hear it works. Since your question was essentially resolved by configuring Texmaker properly would you be OK with closing it as a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864?

Comment: Hey again. The bibliography is not showing again.  I run the same combination of pdf and bibtex and references are not appearing.  Does anyone know why is that and how to solve it?

Comment: As established you need to run **Biber** and *not* BibTeX. If you did run LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX and still don't get any useful output you need to have a look at the `.log` and `.blg` files: They will contain hints as to what is going wrong. In particular the `.blg` is important.

Comment: I meant I run biber, i haven't changed anything from yesterday so don't really know why would it suddenly not work anymore.

Comment: Neither do I, that's why you need to check the `.log` and `.blg` files: Before you do that remove the temporary files (`.aux`, `.bbl`, `.bcf`)  and recompile with the full LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX cycle. If there are any errors, fix them; if you can't fix them, tell us what the error messages say.

Comment: One reference had a foreign symbol so it couldn't be read apparently. thanks again for help :)